# Java is not trowing Arithmetic exception

Tags: java, testng, arithmeticexception

I have this Java code:

```
public class Calc {
    public int quotient(int a, int b){
        return a/b;
    }
}
```

and TestNG unit test for this method:

```
@Test ()
public void testingMethod3() {
    Assert.assertEquals(0, calc.quotient(5,0));
}
```

On my work computer I successfully get

> java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

message, as expected.

But when my colleague runs this test on home computer, then mentioned exception is not throwing and test passes.

How this magic could occur?

P.S.
Environment
OS: Windows 10
TestNG version: 6.13.1
Java version: 8 (don't know exact build version)

P.P.S.
Deletion of target folder and rebuilding of the project was that very helpful solution. Seem like IDE cashed old project sources, and didn't flush them after changes in the code.

Comment: not. not with the same values.

Comment: Copy paste error ?

Comment: your quotient method must throws an exception.

Comment: It's a division by 0... If you friend is telling you that he doesn't get this exception, he is either lying or is using another number than 0 for b.

Comment: I'm not sure about copy paste error.
this code was written at home, and commited to repository.
At work we just pulled it, and ran once again. On both work PCs it worked as expected, with exception.

Comment: Java or TestNG version theme? Was there an exception handling change?

Comment: did your collegue recompile the code before trying to run it?

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for idea. I've suggested to delete target folder, and recompile the project.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I experienced something like yours. Because different JDK compile environment and/or JRE runtime environment. And need check the different of version of TestNG.

check by add few line of code to print Java properties.

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
    String value = (String)p.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

then comparing